# How to add style to inline svg in Angular 2

Tags: angular, svg, inline-svg

```
 <div class="svg_ahu card_content" align="start" [inlineSVG]="'/assets/ahu.svg'"></div>
```

I used this syntax to include SVG in angular2 but not able to style it.

CSS:

```
 #fill1 {
  animation: fill1 .1s ease infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening due to styles encapsulation.

You can use one of 3 options:

- "encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None" for the component with SVG.
- "/deep/ #fill1" selector, to specify that rules should apply to a child component
- you can move SVG styles to the global styles.[s]css file.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

please be aware that it's deprecated

Answer (score 0):

try using like this

```
<div class="svg_ahu card_content" align="start" [attr.inlineSVG]="'/assets/ahu.svg'"></div>
```

`

Comment: any error now in the console ? can you reproduce your problem on some plunker ?

Comment: No error but after using attr.inlineSVG, svg is not showing in the web page.

Comment: what is the solution?